# JQuery Ajax problem with at Chrome brower

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I'm running a site (in a development environment) that has `http://172.31.129.188:8888/pp/` as its base url.

From `http://172.31.129.188:8888/pp/pingpong` I have this ajax call:

```
$.post('pingpong/check/',
    function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
);
```

The problem is that while Firefox and Explorer call `http://172.31.129.188:8888/pp/pingpong/check` (as I want), Chrome makes a call to `http://172.31.129.188:8888/pp/pingpong/pingpong/check`. I've tried various combinations (like adding and removing the slashes etc) but still Chrome seems to have a different approach.

Can anyone help to unify the behavior? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, Chrome is behaving correctly and IE/Firefox are not.  URLs are either absolute with a domain, relative to the domain-base if they start with a slash (/) or relative to the current location.

If you access `b/c` from `/a/b` that should be `/a/b/b/c` not `/a/b/c` as the `b` is relative to the current location, it should not match part of the location and continue from there.  If you need to use relative URLs try calling `check/` to see if that behaves appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Make the call to `/pp/pingpong/pingpong/check`